# Display middleware value in Jade Template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following sample middleware component that I want to display in the index.jade file. Is this possible?  How do you add the `req.requestTime` in the Jade template?

```
var requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now();
  next();
};

app.use(requestTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property to `res.locals` and you can use it in Pug (formerly Jade)

```
var requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now();
  res.locals.requestTime = req.requestTime;
  next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
    req.requestTime = Date.now();
      res.locals.requestTime = req.requestTime;
      next();
};

//Jade renderer
var jadeRenderer = function(req, res) {
    var jadeFile = 'path/to/jade/template';
    var jadeVars = {
        locals: req.locals,
        queryParams: req.query //if you desire?
    };
    res.render(jadeFile, jadeVars, function(err, html) {
        if(err) {
            //handle error
        }
        res.send(html);
    });
};

//jade template
<p>#{locals.requestTime}</p>
```

Comment: is the Jade renderer code needed or can I just reference the requestTime property directly in the template?